# Adding a DataFrame column with len() of another column's values

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-length

I'm having a problem trying to get a character count column of the string values in another column, and haven't figured out how to do it efficiently.

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    df['char_length'][index] = len(df['string'][index]))
```

This apparently involves first creating a column of nulls and then rewriting it, and it takes a really long time on my data set. So what's the most effective way of getting something like

```
'string'     'char_length'
abcd          4
abcde         5
```

I've checked around quite a bit, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pandas has a [vectorised string method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for this: `str.len()`. To create the new column you can write:

```
df['char_length'] = df['string'].str.len()
```

For example:

```
>>> df
  string
0   abcd
1  abcde

>>> df['char_length'] = df['string'].str.len()
>>> df
  string  char_length
0   abcd            4
1  abcde            5
```

This should be considerably faster than looping over the DataFrame with a Python `for` loop.

Many other familiar string methods from Python have been introduced to Pandas. For example, `lower` (for converting to lowercase letters), `count` for counting occurrences of a particular substring, and `replace` for swapping one substring with another.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  string
0   abcd
1  abcde

In [4]: df['len'] = df['string'].str.len()

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  string  len
0   abcd    4
1  abcde    5
```